# $R^2$ from a generalized linear mixed-effects models (GLMM) using a negative binomial distribution

Tags: r, mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, negative-binomial-distribution, glmm

I try to compute the marginal and conditional $R^2$ for a GLMM using a negative binomial distribution by following the procedure recommended by Nakagawa & Schielzeth (2013) . Unfortunately, the supplementary material of their article does not include an example of a negative binomial distribution (see the online version of the article stated below, I also added their code below). 
I fitted my model using the glmmPQL function from the MASS package.

```
full_model  <- glmmPQL ( Y~ a + b + c,  random = ~ 1 +  A | location  
, family = negative.binomial (1.4 ) ,data= mydata
```

In particular, I do have the following problems:

1. First, I need to extract the fixed effect design matrix of my model. However, full_model @X or model.matrix(full_model) does not work. I also tried to set the argument x=TRUE before extracting the matrix. Well, this should not be too tricky, but the following problems are.
2. Second, I need to specify the distribution-speciﬁc variance of my model. Examples in the article (see table 2 & and the supplementary R code of the online article) specify this for a binomial and a Poisson distribution. With some deeper statistical knowledge, it should not be difficult to specify this for a negative binomial distribution.
3. Finally, I would need to know if glmmPQL uses additive dispersion or to multiplicative dispersion. In the paper, they state: "we only consider additive dispersion implementation of GLMMs although the formulae that we present below can be easily modiﬁed for the use with GLMMs that apply to multiplicative dispersion. " Thus, in case glmmPQL uses multiplicative dispersion, I would need further help to adjust the formula.

Can anybody help?

Thanks, best 
Philipp

P.S. R-code is welcome.

Nakagawa & Schielzeth (2013) A general and simple method for obtaining R 2 from generalized linear mixed-effects models. Methods in Ecology and Evolution 2013, 4, 133–142. doi: 10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x

Their R script:

```
  #A general and simple method for obtaining R2 from generalized linear mixed-effects models
  #Shinichi Nakagawa1,2 and Holger Schielzeth3
  #1 National Centre of Growth and Development, Department of Zoology, University of    Otago, Dunedin, New Zealand
  #2 Department of Behavioral Ecology and Evolutionary Genetics, Max Planck Institute for Ornithology, Seewiesen, Germany
  #3 Department of Evolutionary Biology, Bielefeld University, Bielefeld, Germany
  #Running head: Variance explained by GLMMs
  #Correspondence:
  #S. Nakagawa; Department of Zoology, University of Otago, 340 Great King Street,    Dunedin, 9054, New Zealand
  #Tel:  +64 (0)3 479 5046
  #Fax: +64 (0)3 479 7584
  #e-mail: shinichi.nakagawa@otago.ac.nz 


  ####################################################
  # A. Preparation
  ####################################################
  # Note that data generation appears below the analysis section.
  # You can use the simulated data table from the supplementary files to reproduce exactly the same results as presented in the paper.

  # Set the work directy that is used for rading/saving data tables
  # setwd("/Users/R2")

  # load R required packages
  # If this is done for the first time, it might need to first download and install the package
  # install.package("arm")
  library(arm)
  # install.package("lme4")
  library(lme4)


  ####################################################
  # B. Analysis
  ####################################################

  # 1. Analysis of body size (Gaussian mixed models)
  #---------------------------------------------------

  # Clear memory
  rm(list = ls())

  # Read body length data (Gaussian, available for both sexes)
  Data <- read.csv("BeetlesBody.csv")

  # Fit null model without fixed effects (but including all random effects)
  m0 <- lmer(BodyL ~ 1 + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container), data = Data)

  # Fit alternative model including fixed and all random effects
  mF <- lmer(BodyL ~ Sex + Treatment + Condition + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container), data = Data)

  # View model fits for both models
  summary(m0)
  summary(mF)

  # Extraction of fitted value for the alternative model
  # fixef() extracts coefficents for fixed effects
  # mF@X returns fixed effect design matrix
  Fixed <- fixef(mF)[2] * mF@X[, 2] + fixef(mF)[3] * mF@X[, 3] + fixef(mF)[4] * mF@X[, 4]

  # Calculation of the variance in fitted values
  VarF <- var(Fixed)

  # An alternative way for getting the same result
  VarF <- var(as.vector(fixef(mF) %*% t(mF@X)))

  # R2GLMM(m) - marginal R2GLMM
  # Equ. 26, 29 and 30
  # VarCorr() extracts variance components
  # attr(VarCorr(lmer.model),'sc')^2 extracts the residual variance
  VarF/(VarF + VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1] + attr(VarCorr(mF), "sc")^2)

  # R2GLMM(c) - conditional R2GLMM for full model
  # Equ. XXX, XXX
  (VarF + VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1])/(VarF +    VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1] + (attr(VarCorr(mF), "sc")^2))

  # AIC and BIC needs to be calcualted with ML not REML in body size models
  m0ML <- lmer(BodyL ~ 1 + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container), data = Data, REML = FALSE)
  mFML <- lmer(BodyL ~ Sex + Treatment + Condition + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container), data = Data, REML = FALSE)

  # View model fits for both models fitted by ML
  summary(m0ML)
  summary(mFML)


  # 2. Analysis of colour morphs (Binomial mixed models)
  #---------------------------------------------------

  # Clear memory
  rm(list = ls())
  # Read colour morph data (Binary, available for males only)
  Data <- read.csv("BeetlesMale.csv")

  # Fit null model without fixed effects (but including all random effects)
  m0 <- lmer(Colour ~ 1 + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container), family = "binomial", data = Data)

  # Fit alternative model including fixed and all random effects
  mF <- lmer(Colour ~ Treatment + Condition + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container), family = "binomial", data = Data)

  # View model fits for both models
  summary(m0)
  summary(mF)

  # Extraction of fitted value for the alternative model 
  # fixef() extracts coefficents for fixed effects 
  # mF@X returns fixed effect design matrix
  Fixed <- fixef(mF)[2] * mF@X[, 2] + fixef(mF)[3] * mF@X[, 3]

  # Calculation of the variance in fitted values
  VarF <- var(Fixed)

  # An alternative way for getting the same result
  VarF <- var(as.vector(fixef(mF) %*% t(mF@X)))

  # R2GLMM(m) - marginal R2GLMM
  # see Equ. 29 and 30 and Table 2
  VarF/(VarF + VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1] + pi^2/3)

  # R2GLMM(c) - conditional R2GLMM for full model
  # Equ. XXX, XXX
  (VarF + VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1])/(VarF +     VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1] + pi^2/3)


  # 3. Analysis of fecundity (Poisson mixed models)
  #---------------------------------------------------

  # Clear memory
  rm(list = ls())

  # Read fecundity data (Poisson, available for females only)
  Data <- read.csv("BeetlesFemale.csv")

  # Creating a dummy variable that allows estimating additive dispersion in lmer 
  # This triggers a warning message when fitting the model
  Unit <- factor(1:length(Data$Egg))

  # Fit null model without fixed effects (but including all random effects)
  m0 <- lmer(Egg ~ 1 + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container) + (1 | Unit), family = "poisson", data = Data)

  # Fit alternative model including fixed and all random effects
  mF <- lmer(Egg ~ Treatment + Condition + (1 | Population) + (1 | Container) + (1 | Unit), family = "poisson", data = Data)

  # View model fits for both models
  summary(m0)
  summary(mF)

  # Extraction of fitted value for the alternative model 
  # fixef() extracts coefficents for fixed effects 
  # mF@X returns fixed effect design matrix
  Fixed <- fixef(mF)[2] * mF@X[, 2] + fixef(mF)[3] * mF@X[, 3]

  # Calculation of the variance in fitted values
  VarF <- var(Fixed)

  # An alternative way for getting the same result
  VarF <- var(as.vector(fixef(mF) %*% t(mF@X)))

  # R2GLMM(m) - marginal R2GLMM 
  # see Equ. 29 and 30 and Table 2 
  # fixef(m0) returns the estimate for the intercept of null model
  VarF/(VarF + VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Unit[1] + log(1 + 1/exp(as.numeric(fixef(m0)))))

  # R2GLMM(c) - conditional R2GLMM for full model
  # Equ. XXX, XXX
  (VarF + VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1])/(VarF +    VarCorr(mF)$Container[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Population[1] + VarCorr(mF)$Unit[1] + log(1 + 
                                                                       1/exp(as.numeric(fixef(m0)))))


  ####################################################
  # C. Data generation
  ####################################################

  # 1. Design matrices 
  #---------------------------------------------------

  # Clear memory
  rm(list = ls())

  # 12 different populations n = 960
  Population <- gl(12, 80, 960)

  # 120 containers (8 individuals in each container)
  Container <- gl(120, 8, 960)

  # Sex of the individuals. Uni-sex within each container (individuals are sorted at the pupa stage)
  Sex <- factor(rep(rep(c("Female", "Male"), each = 8), 60))

  # Condition at the collection site: dry or wet soil (four indiviudal from each condition in each container)
  Condition <- factor(rep(rep(c("dry", "wet"), each = 4), 120))

  # Food treatment at the larval stage: special food ('Exp') or standard food ('Cont')
  Treatment <- factor(rep(c("Cont", "Exp"), 480))

  # Data combined in a dataframe
  Data <- data.frame(Population = Population, Container = Container, Sex = Sex, Condition = Condition, Treatment = Treatment)


  # 2. Gaussian response: body length (both sexes)
  #---------------------------------------------------

  # simulation of the underlying random effects (Population and Container with variance of 1.3 and 0.3, respectively)
  PopulationE <- rnorm(12, 0, sqrt(1.3))
  ContainerE <- rnorm(120, 0, sqrt(0.3))

  # data generation based on fixed effects, random effects and random residuals errors
  Data$BodyL <- 15 - 3 * (as.numeric(Sex) - 1) + 0.4 * (as.numeric(Treatment) - 1) + 0.15 * (as.numeric(Condition) - 1) + PopulationE[Population] + ContainerE[Container] + 
    rnorm(960, 0, sqrt(1.2))

  # save data (to current work directory)
  write.csv(Data, file = "BeetlesBody.csv", row.names = F)


  # 3. Binomial response: colour morph (males only)
  #---------------------------------------------------

  # Subset the design matrix (only males express colour morphs)
  DataM <- subset(Data, Sex == "Male")

  # simulation of the underlying random effects (Population and Container with variance of 1.2 and 0.2, respectively)
  PopulationE <- rnorm(12, 0, sqrt(1.2))
  ContainerE <- rnorm(120, 0, sqrt(0.2))

  # generation of response values on link scale (!) based on fixed effects and random effects
  ColourLink <- with(DataM, 0.8 * (-1) + 0.8 * (as.numeric(Treatment) - 1) + 0.5 *    (as.numeric(Condition) - 1) + PopulationE[Population] + ContainerE[Container])

  # data generation (on data scale!) based on negative binomial distribution
  DataM$Colour <- rbinom(length(ColourLink), 1, invlogit(ColourLink))

  # save data (to current work directory)
  write.csv(DataM, file = "BeetlesMale.csv", row.names = F)


  # 4. Poisson response: fecundity (females only)
  #---------------------------------------------------

  # Subset the design matrix (only females express colour morphs)
  DataF <- Data[Data$Sex == "Female", ]

  # random effects
  PopulationE <- rnorm(12, 0, sqrt(0.4))
  ContainerE <- rnorm(120, 0, sqrt(0.05))

  # generation of response values on link scale (!) based on fixed effects, random effects and residual errors
  EggLink <- with(DataF, 1.1 + 0.5 * (as.numeric(Treatment) - 1) + 0.1 *   (as.numeric(Condition) - 1) + PopulationE[Population] + ContainerE[Container] +   rnorm(480, 
                                                                                                                                                         0, sqrt(0.1)))

  # data generation (on data scale!) based on Poisson distribution
  DataF$Egg <- rpois(length(EggLink), exp(EggLink))

  # save data (to current work directory)
  write.csv(DataF, file = "BeetlesFemale.csv", row.names = F)
```

Comment: So far I found out that, glmmPQL uses multiplicative dispersion.

Answer (score 2):

For Q1 check out the following paper
http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/2041-210X.12225/full
It says their code is now included in the package "MuMIn".
HTH.

Comment: Can you tell us more about what is in this paper?

Comment: They extended the method by Nakagawa & Schielzeth to make it able to calculate R2 for GLMM with random slopes, not only with random intercept as in Nakagawa & Schielzeth.

Comment: The piecewiseSEM package also implements the method of Nakagawa & Schielzeth, but I have not tired it with a negative binomial model; I also don't know if it works with glmmPQL